# TSQl Exclude all records from table A based on the given criteria from Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I decided to write this topic as I was struggling with one query and I am not getting any further.
I have got two following tables:
- Client Table
- Shipment Table
In Client table (table A) there is a number of clients as below

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|     ClientID        |     CliendCode   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         ABC      |
|          2          |         DEF      |
|          3          |         GHI      |
```

..and in shipment table (table B) there are stored all shipment records and clients corresponding ids.

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|     ShipmentID      |     CliendID     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          100        |         ABC      |
|          101        |         ABC      |
|          102        |         GHI      |
|          301        |         DEF      |
|          302        |         GHI      |
|          303        |         GHI      |
```

What I am trying to achieve is to pull data from table A and table B and get details of those clients and shipment which ShipemtnID do not start from '10' (basically excluding all of the clients if there is at least one shipmentid record in shipment table  starting from '10' 
In this case the result I am looking would be.

```
|     ShipmentID      |     CliendID     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          301        |         DEF      |
```

I have tried apply outer, exists and other statements but none of them provide accurate data.
I will appreciate any help you can offer as I need to finish this report as soon as possible.

Comment: show us what you have tried, so we can analyze what's the problem

Comment: Can you give us the data type of each column? And can you specify what you mean by "start from '10' "?

Comment: Join your tables and add clause WHERE LEFT(CAST(ShipmentID AS VARCHAR(5),2) <> '10'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the below query..

```
  select sh.ShipmentId,sh.ClientId
  from shipments sh
  where not exists(select 1
                     from shipments sh1
                     where sh.clientId = sh1.clientId
                       and sh1.shipmentid like '10%'
                    );
```

Comment: Thank you Unnikrishnan. You help me a lo and the t the report is done.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `not exists` or `not in`:

```
select s.*
from shipments s
where s.clientid not in (select s2.clientid
                         from shipments s2
                         where s2.shipmentid like '10%'
                        );
```